# Search index not updating for new site nodes

Tags: indexing, multisite

I have created new site node and my web site search functionality is not working for the new site.

I have rebuilt the search index from the Indexing Manager and I have checked the indexes, it seems it's not updated for new languages.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello LittleDragon, I think you question is very vague. First of all you said search is not working and then search is not working for new languages? So is it working for current languages? Try placing your indexing configs